# Shortcut and or bat file with login and set affinity

Tags: windows, batch-file, affinity, shortcut-file, ryzom

I have this game I like to play: ryzom.com, it really wasn't built for windows and I'm running windows 10, I have to set the processor affinity each time I start the game (because the default is single 1st core) and I have multiple accounts (that i do not use at the same time, so it's always the same .exe file it's accessing). so I would like to have a desktop shortcut for each account that logs me in (username and password) and sets affinity to all cores (4 for my main computer and 2 for my old computer) for the program.

I know using multiple shortcuts for the login works, I can't get the set affinity to work either by .bat file or in the editing of the target string command of the short cut (probably due to operator error).

the default start shortcut uses `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Ryzom\launch.bat"`
the `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Ryzom\client_ryzom_rd.exe" username password` shortcut also works

The .bat file noted above only contains the following string:
`start client_ryzom_rd.exe`

Any help would be appreciated (and as I'm not the only one fighting this problem, information for 2 core, 4 core, 6 core, and 8 core, and assigning multiple cores like an 8 core using only 1-4 or only even cores would be appreciated)

and if I can't have both at lease the affinity set to all cores.

Comment: you can't set processor affinity through shoortcut. But you can check [shortcutJS.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/shortcutJS.bat) and see how much work it will do for you.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1: START /AFFINITY

Make a shortcut for each CPU core, the shortcuts will pass a CPU affinity mask to `launch.bat`:

Core 1: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Ryzom\launch.bat" 1`
Core 2: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Ryzom\launch.bat" 2`
Core 3: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Ryzom\launch.bat" 4`
Core 4: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Ryzom\launch.bat" 8`
Core 5: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Ryzom\launch.bat" 10`
Core 6: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Ryzom\launch.bat" 20`
Core 7: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Ryzom\launch.bat" 40`
Core 8: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Ryzom\launch.bat" 80`

launch.bat:

```
start "" /affinity %1 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Ryzom\client_ryzom_rd" user pass
```

#### Solution 2: IMAGECFG

Make copies of `client_ryzom_rd.exe` and modify the built-in CPU affinity mask in each exe.

Use [imagecfg](https://robpol86.com/imagecfg.html) utility and the masks from above but with `0x` prefix for two-digit numbers (1, 2, 4, 8, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80):

```
imagecfg -a 0x10 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Ryzom\client_ryzom_rd-CORE5.exe"
```

Then make the shortcuts to each modified exe.